# Drag and drop: Show the draggable element until a condition is verified

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I wrote a function to drag and drop an element into another, this element is an image and after being dragged and dropped in the final position it regenerate itself in its original position.

I want to regenerate this image till a condition is true, when the condition is false it stops to regenerate in his original position. This is the function I wrote, but I can't avoid the image to be regenerate. Any hints? Thanks in advance.

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

    if (nPedR > 0){
     ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
     nPedR--;
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("Drag1").remove();
    }
    console.log(nPedR);
}
```

I post also the chunk of HTML code:

```
<tr>
<td width="50px" height="50px"><img id="drag1" src="red.png" align="center" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></td>
<td width="50px" height="50px"><img id="drag2" src="yellow.png" align="center" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: any idea? I'm stuck...